# How to change background color of dropdown menu on right click?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I can't figure out why is my dropdown menu link changing color when I open it and right click on the menu.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      MyMenu <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Blabla1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blabla2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blabla3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
a {
  background-color: #DDDDFF;
}

.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus,
.nav > li > a:active {
  background-color: #6666FF !important;
}
```

JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/0nLvnhuu/

Any ideas why is that?

Comment: can you describe your issue more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```css
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus,
.nav > li > a:active {
    background-color: #6666FF !important;
}
```

Use this one:

```css
.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover{
    background-color: #6666FF;
}
```

As a standard coding formate we should not use !important in many occasions. So I hope this code would be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the color to change, simply delete the `.nav > li > a:active`. The color will change when you hover over the item because of `.nav > li > a:hover`.
I think `a:focus` doesn't affect your example. 
But in your case just delete `.nav > li > a:active` and `a:focus` and then your problem will be solved.

So just replace it with that:

```css
a {
  background-color: #DDDDFF;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #6666FF !important;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use snippets if you don't have a whole set of working code. Use editor code formatting to format simple code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your menu link changing color on click? Only background color changes and link color stays the same #23527c. As intended in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have these CSS rules:

```css
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus,
.nav > li > a:active {
  background-color: #6666FF !important;
}
```

then, the top menu a element, changes the `background-color` according to the CSS rule on `hover` and `active` (right click) events.

To get rid of the color, just remove the CSS rule.